# Unmarshalling a complicated JSON ad bin it with a struct

Tags: go, struct

I have the following JSOn response from a webhook call

```
{
  "responseId": "d5c70d8b-e8ad-41df-bb3b-26b0e51d60ca-a14fa99c",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "1111111111",
    "parameters": {
      "phone-number": "1111111111"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Thats great! You payment link has been sent to Gaf ( Mobile number 1111111111 )",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [{
      "text": {
        "text": ["Thats great! You payment link has been sent to Far ( Mobile number 1111111111 )"]
      }
    }],
    "outputContexts": [{
      "name": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/sessions/80f2fb70-01d0-fc1d-200a-ccbae5572829/contexts/awaiting_name",
      "lifespanCount": 2,
      "parameters": {
        "name": ["Gar"],
        "name.original": ["Gar"],
        "phone-number": "1111111111",
        "phone-number.original": "1111111111"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/sessions/80f2fb70-01d0-fc1d-200a-ccbae5572829/contexts/awaiting_number",
      "lifespanCount": 4,
      "parameters": {
        "phone-number": "1111111111",
        "phone-number.original": "1111111111"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/sessions/80f2fb70-01d0-fc1d-200a-ccbae5572829/contexts/awaiting_name_confirm",
      "lifespanCount": 3,
      "parameters": {
        "name": ["Gaf"],
        "name.original": ["Far"],
        "phone-number": "1111111111",
        "phone-number.original": "1111111111"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/sessions/80f2fb70-01d0-fc1d-200a-ccbae5572829/contexts/__system_counters__",
      "parameters": {
        "no-input": 0.0,
        "no-match": 0.0,
        "phone-number": "1111111111",
        "phone-number.original": "1111111111"
      }
    }],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/intents/d21f7be5-0f77-4cb8-9857-26ba04964317",
      "displayName": "GetMobileNumber"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {
    }
  },
  "session": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/sessions/80f2fb70-01d0-fc1d-200a-ccbae5572829"
}
```

I wanted to extract out

```
"outputContexts": [{
          "name": "projects/open-prod-bot-pfgibi/agent/sessions/80f2fb70-01d0-fc1d-200a-ccbae5572829/contexts/awaiting_name",
          "lifespanCount": 2,
          "parameters": {
            "name": ["Gar"],
            "name.original": ["Gar"],
            "phone-number": "1111111111",
            "phone-number.original": "1111111111"
          }
        }
```

out of this and bind this with a struct. But I couldn't do it. I am trying to loop it through the map as below

```
var f interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

    for k, v := range f.(map[string]interface{}) {
        if k == "queryResultmap" {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }
```

but not working. I am new to Go. Tried few examples in google but since this one is a complicated JSON I am unable to do it. Please help

Comment: `if k == "queryResult" { ... }` will give you the output that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you declare a struct with the fields you care about and unmarshal into that, but if you want to stick to `interface{}` try this:

```
m := f.(map[string]interface{})
r := m["queryResult"].(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(r["outputContext"])
```

https://play.golang.com/p/gA5wWcPyd6E

Using struct:

```
type OutputContext struct {
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    LifespanCount int    `json:"lifespanCount"`
    Parameters    struct {
        Name                []string `json:"name"`
        NameOriginal        []string `json:"name.original"`
        PhoneNumber         string   `json:"phone-number"`
        PhoneNumberOriginal string   `json:"phone-number.original"`
        NoInput             float64  `json:"no-input"`
        NoMatch             float64  `json:"no-match"` 
    } `json:"parameters"`
}

type QueryResult struct {
    OutputContexts []OutputContext `json:"outputContexts"`
}

// ...

var dest struct {
    QueryResult QueryResult `json:"queryResult"`
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &dest); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, v := range dest.QueryResult.OutputContexts {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/EfIugDQJ651

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to edit your answer with struct binding as well. I would like try the standard way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to store PhoneNumber to a variable ?

Comment: @Ajeesh then you would store it into a variable as you would anything else. Anything specific that's not clear how assignment from a struct field would work?

Comment: fmt.Println(k, v.Parameters.Name) this is not working :(

Comment: @Ajeesh What do you mean it's not working, it does work for me, what error are you seeing?

Comment: It works now. Some issue with go playground, the code was getting timed out